# Pure CSS Checkbox button with no label (jQuery is a possible solution)

Tags: css, checkbox, label

I'm trying to replace a checkbox and make it into a button. I've done this before, but for this site I'm using Easy Digital Downloads Front End Submissions. I've searched and searched, also gone through multiple posts here on the site.

I don't know how this was made, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it as the label seems to come before the class. It has this selectit class I've been trying to mess around with, but whatever I do I can't make a button.

When I try something like `input[type=checkbox] + label` it doesn't actually affect anything.
Other examples would be `.selectit input[type=checkbox]:before` This one works.
As well as `.selectit input:checked:after`
But again, I can't add anything with `+ label` it seems.

Well I can make one that has a hover, but not one with a checked state and a color change for example.

I should note that I **cannot change any HTML**. The way the checkbox is built, I have to stick with, <strike>so I'm trying to make a pure CSS solution.</strike> But I can add jquery into the page

Here's the HTML for the checkboxes. I only really want the parent checkbox to be affected by the hover and checked state.

```html
<ul class="fes-category-checklist">
  <li id="download_category-156" data-open="false" style="display: list-item;"><label class="selectit"><input value="156" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-156"> 2D Assets</label>
    <ul class="children">

      <li id="download_category-183" data-open="false"><label class="selectit"><input value="183" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-183"> Motion Graphics</label></li>

      <li id="download_category-163" data-open="false"><label class="selectit"><input value="163" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-163"> HDRI</label></li>

      <li id="download_category-162" data-open="false"><label class="selectit"><input value="162" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-162"> Materials</label></li>

      <li id="download_category-161" data-open="false"><label class="selectit"><input value="161" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-161"> Textures</label></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I hope someone has some answers
Thanks!

***EDIT***

I was advised to update my question, because I can insert jquery into the page. Although, this is not something I have much experience with myself.

Comment: Any images you might have? Something drawn at least?

Comment: I don't know if this helps
First checkbox is checked, I have just styled the label that's next to it. But for some reason can't target with the actual checkbox
Second one I'm hovering over, and the third one is neutral
https://pasteboard.co/HXZJI8C.png
https://pasteboard.co/HXZJWa5.png

Comment: There's nothing wrapping the text after `input`. It's kinda not possible with the current HTML. To target checked box, you need to use `:checked` pseudo element and `+` sibling selector.

Comment: And changing the HTML is unfortunately not possible.
But is it still possible to do with sibling selector then?

Comment: Can't use sibling, no. The input is a child of the label. I don't suppose you can use JS at all? :)

Comment: Actually I can put some JQuery and Javascript on the page. So we're in luck there I guess :D?

Comment: We sure are. I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Original, no javascript, crazy answer

Your problem is that you can't select a parent of an element, and so you can't say "if this box is checked, make its parent label change color." Sadly, the `:has` CSS selector isn't supported by anything, or that could save you.

However. If you're insane, and you hate it when things look nice, you can do some crazy stuff with outlines and margins. This is *mucho janky* but it sort of works. Kinda.

You can play around with it in this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPQJgw

### Follow-up, non-crazy, uses jQuery answer

Okay your edit says you can use javascript or jQuery. Let's assume you already have jQuery loaded on the page, since that makes for short code.

**Codepen here:** https://codepen.io/tobyinternet/pen/daYqJq

I'll explain what's up here.

You can't change the HTML, but (with javascript) you CAN assign classes to elements. So first, we create classes that modify the existing elements.

- Strip bullets off list items
- Hide the actual checkboxes
- Make the labels into block elements and give them colors and hover states
- Create a style to indicate when a "button" is "checked"

Then we use javascript to first apply button styles on page load, then apply appropriate checked/unchecked style when an element is clicked.

The purpose of doing it this way is that if a user can't (or doesn't want to) use javascript, they just see checkboxes. Still totally usable, good for accessibility. If they *do* have javascript installed, then ta-da! Buttons.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fes-category-checklist, .fes-category-checklist .children').addClass('nolist');
  
  $('.selectit').addClass('checkbutton');
  
  $('.checkbutton').click(function(){
    if( $(this).children('input:checkbox').is(':checked') ) {
         $(this).addClass('ischecked');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('ischecked');
    }
  });  
  
});
```

```css
.nolist {
  list-style: none;
}

.nolist li {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.checkbutton {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-right: -130px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: all .2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(50,50,50,.5);
}

.checkbutton:hover {
  background-color: #CCCC00;
}

.checkbutton:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(50,50,50,.5);
}

.checkbutton input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -99999px;
}

.ischecked {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.ischecked:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="fes-category-checklist">
  <li id="download_category-156" data-open="false" style="display: list-item;"><label class="selectit"><input value="156" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-156"> 2D Assets</label>
    <ul class="children">

      <li id="download_category-183" data-open="false"><label class="selectit"><input value="183" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-183"> Motion Graphics</label></li>

      <li id="download_category-163" data-open="false"><label class="selectit"><input value="163" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-163"> HDRI</label></li>

      <li id="download_category-162" data-open="false"><label class="selectit"><input value="162" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-162"> Materials</label></li>

      <li id="download_category-161" data-open="false"><label class="selectit"><input value="161" type="checkbox" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-161"> Textures</label></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This cracked me up! Definitely kind of a solution :D
Don't if the reply shows up, but yes it's possible to use JQuery and Javascript

Comment: Oh well dang, if you can use jquery this becomes trivially easy. Pure CSS is the real challenge here. I’m on a phone right now but you should update your question, you’ll get a good answer!

Comment: Okay, I got it up and running! It's amazing what you can do with this.
I ran into a bit of a problem though, and I've made a codepen to best show it off. I wouldn't know how to explain it properly

But I have another script running on the page as well.
This script allows me to click a parent category, which then unhides all the children below it. If I then click the same parent category or any other parent category, all the children are then unselected.

The problem with these two scripts on the same page, is that the deselection seems to be broken now
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErVzQr

Comment: Glad you got it going! If you'd mark my answer as the solution, that would be cool. I think you have a different kind of problem on your hands now, it'd be worth posting as a separate jQuery-related question. I wouldn't have time to look at your new codepen for at least a few days!